# Basic question on constructing a homomorphism between two cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We want to find a non-trivial homomorphism between $Z_3$ and $Z_{24}$. 
If we have $f:Z_3 \rightarrow Z_{24}$ then all I can really say form the properties of homomorphism that $f(0) = 0$ since the identity in $Z_3$ must be mapped to identity in $Z_{24}$. Just from knowing that, how can I go about making the function? Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $0 = f(1 + 1 + 1) = f(1) + f(1) + f(1)$, we have $3f(1) = 0$.  So the problem reduces to solving the linear congruence

$$3x \equiv 0 \bmod 24$$

Clearly, $x_0 = 0$ is a particular solution and $\gcd(3, 24) = 3$.  Therefore all solutions are given by $x = 0 + (24/3)t = 8t$ where $t \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Hence, the only homomorphisms are $f(1) = 0$, $f(1) = 8$ and $f(1) = 16$.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to figure this out using the hint from vadim123. I needed to look at 3f(1) = 0 a little closer. Since we know f(1) is a element in $Z_{24}$ then we can look at the solutions and we are done. Also f(2) = 16 right, not f(1) = 16.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $1+1+1=0$ so $$0=f(0)=f(1+1+1)=f(1)+f(1)+f(1)$$

Comment: So we know 3f(1) = 0 which implies f(1) = 0, so both 0, 1 map to 0. Now we just need to figure out what 2 maps to?

Comment: If indeed $f(1)=0$, then also $f(2)=f(1)+f(1)=0$.  But that's not the only possibility...

Comment: If we do that then we get the trivial homomorphism. Let me try think of the other possibility.

Comment: @user77404, here's a bonus hint: If you replaced $Z_{24}$ with $Z_{25}$, no nontrivial homomorphism exists.

Comment: Your bonus hint makes sense now, thanks.